# MySQL 'WHERE AND' issue

Tags: mysql, select

I've got an issue, I am trying to collect a number of defined emails from a database, I collect them via the ID of each client.

Therefore, I currently have 1000 users in the database and I only want the emails from IDs 10, 11, 23, 34, 56, 33, 340, 433, 434, etc...

Besides the "

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=10 OR id=11 OR id=23 OR id=34...
```

etc" is there any other method that I could includes all the IDs simultaneously without having to write an OR condition each time and ID is added?

Thank you.

Comment: I've edited your question. In order to indicate the answer that helped you solve your issue, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IN` operator:

```
WHERE id in (10, 11, 23, 34, ....)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN`

```
SELECT email 
FROM users 
WHERE ID IN (34, 56, 33, 340, 433, 434)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE id IN (10, 11, 23, 34, 56, 33, 340, 433, 434);
```